# genfromtxt() artifact when displaying floats

Tags: numpy, scipy

In numpy, I'm reading an ASCII file (see below) using `np.genfromtxt()`

```
0.085 102175 0.00025
0.094 103325 0.00030

raw = genfromtxt(fn)
```

When checking `raw` I get the following:

```
>>> raw[0,0]
0.085000000000000006
```

How do I prevent the artifact `6` at the end and where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour, and is due to the fundamental imprecision of floating point arithmetic. In other words, `0.085` cannot be represented exactly in floating point bits. For this reason, it's generally a good idea to assume a bit of noise in any numerical calculations.